# How would you escape dollar sign in NSIS?

Tags: nsis, dollar-sign

I need to use the SVN tag `$Revision$` within an NSIS script. Obviously the NSIS compiler understands this $Revision as a variable. How could I escape this dollar?

I tried backslash, it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

`MessageBox MB_OK "SVN tag $$Revision$$ "`

Comment: Doubling the dollar sign does work. Is there a more elegant way to parse the revision number interger part than the way I am doing hereafter? I define a witty constant  `!Define BUILD_TAG "$$Revision$Empty"`, then declare a variable `$Empty` as an empty string, and finally use `StrStr` applied on `BUILD_TAG` to extract the integer part at the end. You've got it that `$Empty` is used here to absorb the trailing $ left by the SVN tag.